# Migration to androidX - can't import/find androidx.databinding.DatabindingUtil

Tags: android, gradle, mvvm, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

I'm working on an Android MVVM application. I just switched to the androidx libraries manually. This are the libraries in my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:2.0.0-rc01"
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

I changed everything in the code and layout files, all the imports and such. 
Gradle can build succesfully.

In my MainActivity I have the following code:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel);
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

This is the only package in my MainActivity that won't show the androidx version of it:

> import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

Every other package showed the `androidx` version of himself. When I remove the import I can only choose the `android` version and not the `androidx`.

I get an error in: `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);`
That's because the `DatabindingUtil` still refers to the `android.databinding` package instead of the `androidx.databinding` package. My Android Studio tells me that the parameter passed to the method setLifecycleOwner must be of type: `anndroid.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner`.

I don't know why I can't import the `androidx.databinding.DatabindingUtil` package. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

I did try to rebuild and invalidate cache & restart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to do it manually. So I upgraded to Android Studio 3.2 RC 2. 
After that I used the migrate function of Android Studio.

For the migrate function in Android Studio go to > Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...

When Android Studio gives you errors after that, try to Rebuild or maybe use > File > Invalidate Cache & Restart.

As @cchcc pointed out, don't forget to add this to your `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: `gradle.properties` seem to be automatically updated by recent AS when doing `Migrate to AndroidX`, so no need to manual intervention.

Comment: This was driving me nuts, turned out the project started as a non migrated one and we manually added the required implementation stuff in gradle. Adding this fixed the issue.

Comment: @476rick can you add if you (or Android Studio) eventually changed the import `import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;` to something else? I get the same error message but I can't find the namespace `androidx.databindng...` Did you change it eventually or not?

Comment: @BrunoBieri The correct import is: import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil; I do not remember if Android Studio did it or that I did it manually. You can try to Rebuild or to: Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 13):

I was missing the

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha. I was confusing ViewBinding with Databinding.

Answer (score 6):

1. Be sure you are using Android Studio 3.2 RC 2
2. Add 2 lines below in `gradle.properties` file

   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it by doing it via the new Android Studio 3.2 RC2. The important thing was to do it by using > Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...